# Can you display the first element of a ListBox rather than create a data template for xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

The following Binding is on an IEnumerable called activity. The thing is, in my xaml... I only want to output the first element in the array. can you do something along these lines:

```
<Run Text="{Binding activity[0].created_by.name}"></Run>
```

Or do you have to link up another data template for the activity IEnumerable array?

Here is the property of the ActivityStream class (I now notice it's a List..hmm.)

```
...
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> activity { get; set; }
...
```

And here is where i do PropertyChanged yada yada stuff

```
    public IEnumerable<JamesStream> activityStream;

...

    private async void LoadActivityStreamSection()
    {
        activityStreamRepository = new JamesStreamRepository();
        var tempActivityStream = await activityStreamRepository.GetAllBySpaceId(space.space_id);

        activityStream = tempActivityStream;
        ActivityStream = null;

        //The Activitiy Stream has a property which is of type List<object> called activity
        // In my xaml I just want to be outputting the 1st entry of the List<object> property .created_by_name
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler tempEvent = PropertyChanged;

        if (tempEvent != null)
        {
            // property changed
            tempEvent(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<JamesStream> ActivityStream
    {
        get
        {
            return activityStream;
        }
        set
        {
            if (activityStream != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ofcourse. It didn't work. :) Was it supposed to?

Comment: I'm very confused. Where do you state that `activity` changed? Why all this code about `ActivityStream` when your xaml does not refer to it?

Comment: ActivityStream is filled with the contents of an API call... a my ActivityStream data contract deals with all the bits and bobs returned (and the class came from json to c# tool). The ActivityStream is a ListBox binding, and the above are data templates for the child properties of ActivityStream; one of which is activity. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If your IEnumerable has a .First property, you may be able to attach to that?

Comment: Is this something I need to code myself? so add an additional property to the activity that just represents the first element? Actually just tried .First and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

your code works...normally :).

Can you show how do you fill your collection? I think it's maybe because you don't fire INotifyPropertyChanged (or INotify-like for collection) event

Comment: Change for an ObservableCollection<T> or load your activity List in the Constructor (not a good practice). Actually, your binding isn't notified about a change in your collection.

Comment: Is this all because it is an "object" rather than a pre-defined class?

Comment: in WPF that works but on WP or WinRT...sometime it's strange so can be that yes.

Comment: In fact, just for test purposes I prepared a data template and sure enough the properties are not working. so yes, the fact I have not explicitly defined the class and just left it as type object, means it is not working arghhh... they are of varying types. I'll have to do a switch on the set I guess and do a variant type T on the activity property instead or something :S. This is going to hurt me.

Comment: P.S making a property = null successfully runs the notification to the property throughout my application, so I think it's just the object bit causing the problem.

Comment: Or you can implement a common interface who describes the values to bind. or with a converter, you bind your object and the converter select the right cast/value to return.